# wc command with no FILE argument (reading from standard input)

Tags: stdin, wc

Regarding `wc` (word count) command... I am trying to understand the following (from `man wc` which I have quoted below plus added a longer quote at end of my question)

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

How exactly does this work? At what point do I type the "standard input"?

Finding explanations online rather confusing. Maybe I am just missing some basic info regarding what exactly `stdin` is.

From `man wc`

```
SYNOPSIS 
     wc [OPTION]... [FILE]... wc [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
         
DESCRIPTION 
     Print newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total
     line if more than one FILE is specified. A word is a
     non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.
         
     With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Answer (score 4):

`wc`, the program, detects when there's 0 filenames, or just "`-`", on the command line, e.g.

```
wc
wc -
```

and, in those cases, reads from -`STDIN` (Stream 0 for the process). You never need to "type standard input".

The "parent process", the one that creates a process, is responsible for setting up 3 I/O streams:

```
0 STDIN - program input
1 STDOUT - normal program output
2 STDERR - error program output
```

It's up to the program to read from `STDIN`, if it wants to.

An example of using `wc` to read from the standard input stream:

```bsh
$ echo 'hello world' | wc
      1       2      12
```

Here, `wc` counts the number of lines, words, and characters arriving on its standard input stream.  That stream is connected to the standard output stream of the `echo` command by the shell via a pipe.  The `echo` command sends the string `hello world` to its standard output stream, and `wc` receives it.

Comment: Of course, if there is no redirection from a file, pipe, HereDoc or HereString, the default is that `wc -` *will* have the terminal as its stdin. In which case, you type your "file" directly into the keyboard, and terminate that file by typing Ctrl-D on a line by itself. This kind of agnostic inheritance is a fundamental part of Unix-like systems.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The real MVP is always in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was unfamiliar with using `ctrl+d` to "end terminal line input" (after typing input text).

I suppose it's basic knowledge for using the command line - but something I was unable to figure out by reading the man page and googling how to use the wc command extensively.

Step by step for any other confused beginners out there:

Type `wc -` in terminal and hit `ENTER`.

Now you can start typing your input.

When you are done, press `ctrl+d`

Comment: It's not on the man page, or most other things about `wc`, because it's not specific to or different in any way for `wc` -- it's the same for nearly ALL programs on Unix; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Comment: Yes these kinds of realizations come more quickly and easily with some experience.